# Why my css doesnt apply to any new div/section

Tags: html, css

My CSS is not getting applied to my any of new divs that I add even after using `!important` or /deep/ and checking syntax and class name 10 times still no result I guess its some problem that I have no idea

```js
function isvalid() {
  var user = document.form.user.value;
  var pass = document.form.pass.value;
  if (user.length == "" && pass.length == "") {
    alert(" Username and password field is empty");
    return false;
  } else if (user.length == "") {
    alert(" Username field is empty");
    return false;
  } else if (pass.length == "") {
    alert(" Password field is empty");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  ;
  100% {
    opacity: 100
  }
  ;
}

@keyframes aaa {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes blurin {
  0% {
    filter: blur(20px);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(1px);
  }
}

* {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  animation: blurin 0.5s ease;
  background-image: url("img/1.jpg");
}

.header {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #70409c;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.37);
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  font-size: 10px;
  animation: aaa 1s ease-in;
}

.header a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#user {
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blueviolet;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(118, 78, 156, 0.562);
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(49, 25, 136);
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  margin-top: 10rem;
  animation: aaa 2s ease-in;
}

.box1 h1 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#pw {
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blueviolet;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#btn {
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blueviolet;
  padding-left: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  width: 90px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(219, 208, 208);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.box {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <h1 class="">This site contains <a class="a">R-18</a> please be caucius visiting our site</h1>
</section>
<div class="box">
  <a href="reg.php">Click here to register</a>
</div>
<section class="content">
  <div class="box1">
    <h1>Login Panel</h1>
    <form name="form" method="POST" class="bbc" action="login.php">
      <label>Login</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="username"><br>
      <label>Password</label><br>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pw" placeholder="Password"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Login" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code! There's quite a lot of it, though. Can you isolate the problem to a smaller section? If you can replicate the problem with just one CSS statement and a little HTML, it'll be much easier for people to help. Also then you can be more specific about what's not being applied.

Comment: yea, so whats not getting applied is the div with class name "box" that contains the <a href> right, whatever I do with it it just doenst seem to work, in specific i mean this part 
        <div class="box">
            <a href="reg.php">Click here to register</a>
        </div>

Comment: Which rules aren't being applied? if you're referring to the text-decoration not being applied to the anchor within the div, that's because you're setting the rule on the div and not the anchor

Comment: the ones in the css with .box{    text-decoration: none;  
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
https://imgur.com/a/bbojZOP

Comment: If that's the statement that's not working, first try taking everything else out of your css/html that isn't relevant to that. If it's still not working, then you can update the question to be simpler and much easier for people to solve. Otherwise it's hard to see why that css isn't being applied.

Comment: well as you told me that I tried changing it into html format and deleting eveyrhitng it worked ,reverted the delteion of unnecesary code and it worked but while I restarted xampp  ect, it doesnt work on php file format, even after deleting everything other than this line of class code

Comment: In your code snippet you've supplied, all of the css rules for the .box class seem to be working as expected. Could you help us isolate the issue your having, or at least recreate the problem in your provided snippet?

Comment: it maybe that the snipplet is not a php file format beacouse as I said it worked good on index.html name but while trying to run it on localhost with xampp as with index.php name it doesnt work (somehow)

Comment: @K0cM0c okay, that's helpful context to add to the question! That tells you the problem *probably* isn't just with the CSS, since it's working locally. You mention that you've tried deleting everything but the relevant code. I'd suggest updating the question to include *just* the code (html, css, php, js???) necessary to replicate the problem, and under what conditions (html? php? local? xampp?) it occurs. Otherwise very hard to see what's going wrong.

Comment: ive restarted pc and works back again, I LOVE XAMPP